# How to set duration to a video - android

Tags: android, video, mediastore

I am trying to save a 10sec long mp4 file in the gallery (the goal is to upload the vid to facebook).
The log says to me that the file duration is 10sec long - as he should be, but when I'm trying to upload it to Facebook (manually), it appears like the video is 0sec long and I can't upload it. 
 (if I'm watching the video on the phone - its works normally, just when I trying to upload it t FB its happens)

```
private void addVideoGallery( File file ) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION,10000);
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    Log.d("dur",""+values.getAsLong(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION));
    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

I just want to know if I'm setting the duration right (the actual duration is fixed on 10sec), or I should change/update anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, i just used the MediaScanner like this:

```
    Intent intent =
      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For further information: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/